# Additional RAM memory not recognized

Tags: ram

I am using ASUS laptop with 4GB in-built RAM memory.
My operating system is Ubuntu 17.10 (64-bit).
After inserting additional 4GB into free slot, memory amount is still recognized as 4GB by most utilities.
However, if I run `sudo lshw -short -C memory` the new memory card is listed.

Could you help me diagnose this problem, please?

Here are some outputs of memory-specific utilities:

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3,7G        1,1G        1,4G        251M        1,2G        2,2G
Swap:          8,0G          0B        8,0G


sudo lshw -short -C memory
H/W path         Device           Class          Description
============================================================
/0/0                              memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/8                              memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/9                              memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/a                              memory         3MiB L3 cache
/0/b                              memory         4GiB System Memory
/0/b/0                            memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
/0/b/1                            memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/b/2                            memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/b/3                            memory         DIMM [empty]


sudo lshw -C memory
[sudo] password for tomek: 
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: X55VD.409
       date: 01/08/2013
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 6080KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect 
socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 
int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb 
smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 8
       slot: CPU Internal L2
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: internal write-through unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:1
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 9
       slot: CPU Internal L1
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: internal write-through data
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: a
       slot: CPU Internal L3
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: b
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns)
          product: EBJ40UG8BBU0-GN-F
          vendor: Elpida
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 1
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 2
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 3
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1

sudo dmidecode --type memory
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Elpida
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: EBJ40UG8BBU0-GN-F 
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MT/s

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
```

Comment: Did you add it while the system is running, or when the system was powered down?

Comment: I added it when the system was powered down.

Comment: Check in BIOS first and on memtest (from LIveCD or GRUB).

Comment: Does the system firmware (BIOS, UEFI, etc.) see the stick of RAM installed?  It looks to me like *maybe* it's not actually recognizing the type of RAM it provides.

Comment: `lshw` does not show two 4GB modules installed. It shows only one. If you have two, one of them is not being recognized.

Comment: First consult the documentation of your laptop to make sure the new RAM module is supported. If it does, make sure the module is inserted properly. By this I mean that the contacts are all the way in the slot. If so, go into the BIOS and select Load Defaults, reboot and go into the BIOS again to check what Thomas Ward commented. If all that still does not show the additional RAM, contact Asus or a specialized laptop vendor.

Comment: Thank you. That was my fault, the stick wasn't inserted properly.

Comment: @tomekn   Please add your remark into an Answer, so the issue can be closed.